# Populating One to Many Relationship JSON to Core Data

Tags: ios, json, core-data

Having problems with populating a one to many core data model through JSON.

Background:

```
Two Entities:

    WorkoutType
    Attributes:
        -workoutType
    Relationship: workouts
    Destination: WorkoutSet
    Inverse: workoutType

    WorkoutSet
    Attributes:
        -workoutName
    Relationship: workoutType
    Destination: WorkoutType
    inverse: workouts
```

Below is my JSON:

```
[
  { "workoutType": "Strength",
           "workouts":
            [   { "workoutName": "Strength 1"},
                { "workoutName": "Strength 2"},
                { "workoutName": "Strength 3"},
                { "workoutName": "Strength 4"}
                ],
  },
  { "workoutType": "Core",
           "workouts":
            [   { "workoutName": "Core 1"},
                { "workoutName": "Core 2"},
                { "workoutName": "Core 3"},
                { "workoutName": "Core 4"}
                ],
 }
]
```

The JSON parses correctly, the problem is that for each WorkoutType (Core and Strength) There should be 4 workouts (Strength 1, Strength 2,....) ..(Core 1, Core 2,....).

What i achieve after viewing the sqlite database created is that Strength has 3 workouts and Core has 5 workouts. Each time i compile the code the numbers change.

The code i am using is below:

```
    NSString* thirdDataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Workouts" ofType:@"json"];
    NSArray* Workouts = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:thirdDataPath]
                                                       options:kNilOptions
                                                         error:&err];
    NSLog(@"Imported Workouts: %@", Workouts);

    [Workouts enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        WorkoutType *workoutType = [NSEntityDescription
                          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"WorkoutType"
                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
        workoutType.workoutType = [obj objectForKey:@"workoutType"];



        NSArray *workoutsArray = [obj objectForKey:@"workouts"];
        [workoutsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id workoutsObj, NSUInteger workoutsIdx, BOOL *workoutsStop) {


            WorkoutSet *workoutSet = [NSEntityDescription
                                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"WorkoutSet"
                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];


            //Not Sure if the line below is correct, also not sure if i should be setting the relationship here too something like workoutSet.workouts = .... 
            workoutSet.workoutType = workoutType;
            workoutSet.workoutName = [workoutsObj objectForKey:@"workoutName"];
        }];

        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

    }];
```

Be easy please i am a newbie.  within the code i have added a comment where i think i may be making a mistake.

Will be grateful for any help. thank you.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you should pull your call to `save:` out of your `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` call.  There's no need to save 8 times in row.  Do one save when you're done with all your insertions. This won't deal with the problem you asked about, but it will make your code slightly more efficient.

Comment: Also, after reviewing your code a few times I don't see anything wrong with it.  I'm wondering if you're perhaps seeing some old data in your DB from a previous run.  Did you try deleting your DB and doing a fresh run?  I can't see the rest of your app's code, but it looks like you're just going to keep accumulating new entities each time you run this code.

Comment: Yep each time i compile i delete the previously created database.

Comment: Also upon analysing the sqlite database, each workoutName should be related to a WorkoutType. In the database  only Strength 4 and Core 4 are related to their corresponding WorkoutType (Strength and Core) this is shown in terms of numbers (1 and 2) but all the other entries have Null